# File in IOS bundle is not found in the simulator

Tags: ios, bundle, cocos3d, file-not-found

I am working on an ios 6.1 application, that uses cocos3d, i have a file that is
certainly in the bundle, which is 'CC3TexturableMaterial.vsh', but at a point in
time when the applications needs that file, it crashes and shows the following error:

```
[***ERROR***] Could not load GLSL file '/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/3505ADEC-C70B-490F-9011-A433D85C2D66/3D.app/CC3TexturableMaterial.vsh' because it could not be found
```

Which implies that the file is not in the simulator's .app.
does anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Have you checked the build settings to ensure that the file is being copied across? (It's under Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.)

Comment: Foolishly i put it in the compile sources instead of the copy bundle. Thanks, if you could put it in an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can happen when the file isn't explicitly being copied to the bundle.

To check this, ensure that it appears within the "`Build Phases`" -> "`Copy Bundle Resources`" section within your project's build settings. (To view the main build settings, select "`Project`" -> "`Target`" from within the left hand pane).

Comment: Thanks! Here i had some orphaned files - after deleting the references in Build phases everything was fine

Comment: still working at 2022

Answer (score 0):

Just open terminal

```
pod deintegrate
```

and then

```
pod install
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just Follow Below Step:**

1)Select your **project** from the left panel.

2) Select the **target** and then select **Build Phases**

3) There you should fin a button called **Add Build Phase** *(Bottom right side)*

4) There will appear a box where you have to select the files (there's a little `+`sign). And be sure you selected `Destination: Products directory`

Build the project, run it and now it should work !!